# unable to create second deck from same code for a queue

Tags: insert, stack, queue

I have to set up a queue class that implements from a deque class. I need to use this to set up two deck cards with a random order. I have the code below, it works when the first deck is created but for some reason it does not work with the second deck, its the same code that im reusing.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at prog.pkg4.Deque.insertOnBack(Prog4.java:93)
at prog.pkg4.Queue.insert(Prog4.java:153)
at prog.pkg4.Prog4.createDeck(Prog4.java:465)
at prog.pkg4.Prog4.topTrump(Prog4.java:444)
at prog.pkg4.Prog4.main(Prog4.java:287)
```

initiates the two decks

```
Queue player = new Queue();
Queue computer = new Queue();
player = createDeck(player, cards);
computer = createDeck(computer, cards);
```

code to create random deck

```
public static Queue createDeck(Queue queue, GreekHero[] cards){
Random rand = new Random();
int temp = 0;
int r;
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    r = rand.nextInt(30);
    cards[temp] = cards[i];
    cards[i] = cards[r];
    cards[r] = cards[temp];
}
for(int i = 0; i < 29; i++){
    queue.insert(cards[i]);
    System.out.println(queue.insertions());
    System.out.println(queue);
}
return queue;
```

}

```
class Queue{
private Deque queue;

public Queue(){
    queue = new Deque();
}
public void insert(Object o){
    queue.insertOnBack(o);
}
public Object delete(){
    return queue.deleteFromFront();
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return queue.isEmpty();
}
public String toString(){
    return queue.toString();
}
public int insertions(){
    return queue.getInsertions();
}
}
```

i've tested out the deque code several times i know it works, as demonstrated by the first deck that is created, im just not sure what could be causing the problem for the second deck.

EDIT: I've added the Deque class code below, the way i have this set up is that if the number of insertions equals the size of the array, it should double in size, as mentioned before it works with the first deque but on the second deque it stops at size of array - 1. I've increased the size to test out and I could make it bigger to satisfy this project but I need to create a deque with an increasing array.

```
class Deque{
private Object[] arrayObject;
private int beggining; //tracks first element in array
private int insertions; //counts the items in the array
private static int SIZE = 30; //size of array

public Deque(){
    arrayObject = new Object[SIZE];
    beggining = 0;
    insertions = 0;
}
// displays position of first element in circular array
public Object getBeggining(){
    int temp = beggining + 1;
    if(temp == SIZE)
        temp = 0;
    return temp;
}
public int getInsertions(){
    return insertions;
}
public Object indexOne(){
    int temp = beggining + 1;
    if(temp == SIZE)
        temp = 0;
    return arrayObject[temp];
}
public String toString(){
    if(isEmpty())
        return "Empty";
    int temp = beggining + 1;
        if( temp >= SIZE)
            temp = 0;
    String s = "Current Index:\n[("+arrayObject[temp]+")";
    int loops = 0;
    for(int i = temp + 1; loops < insertions - 1; i++){
        if(i >= SIZE)
            i = 0;
        s += ", ("+arrayObject[i]+")";
        loops++;
    }
    s += "]";
    return s;
}
public String toStore(){
    String s = "Store Index:\n[(1: "+arrayObject[1]+")";
    for(int i = 1; i <= SIZE - 1; i++)
        s += ", ("+(i+1)+": "+arrayObject[i]+")";
    s += "]";
    return s;
}
public void insertOnFront(Object o){
    if(insertions == SIZE)
        arrayObject = increaseArray();
    arrayObject[beggining] = o;
    beggining--;
    if(beggining < 0)
        beggining = SIZE - 1;
    insertions++;
}
public Object deleteFromFront(){
    if(isEmpty())
        return null;
    int count = beggining + 1;
        if(count >= SIZE)
            count = 0;
    Object temp = arrayObject[count];
    beggining += 1;
    insertions--;
    if(insertions > 0)
        insertions = 0;
    return temp;
}
public void insertOnBack(Object o){
    int temp = beggining + insertions + 1;
    if(insertions == SIZE - 1)
        arrayObject = increaseArray();
    if(temp >= SIZE)
        temp = 0 + (temp - SIZE);
    arrayObject[temp] = o;
    insertions++;
}
public Object deleteFromBack(){
    if(isEmpty())
        return null;
    int count = beggining + insertions;
    Object temp = arrayObject[count];
    insertions--;
    if(insertions >= 0)
        insertions = 0;
    return temp;
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    if(insertions > 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
public Object[] increaseArray(){
    SIZE *= 2;
    int loops = 0;
    int j = beggining;
    Object[] newArray = new Object[SIZE];
    for(int i = j; loops <= SIZE/2; i++){
        if(j >= SIZE/2)
            j = 0;
        newArray[i] = arrayObject[j];
        loops++;
        j++;
    }
    return newArray;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by moving the SIZE variable as an instance variable of the class and removed static from it. I don't know why the issue popped in on the second iteration rather than on the first try, ill look it up later, if anyone knows please post it here.